# Argument 3 passed to Vendor\\Customer\\Plugin\\EmailNotificationPlugin::aroundnewAccount()

Tags: magento2

Is anything missing in below code?

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Customer\Plugin;

class EmailNotificationPlugin
{
   public function aroundnewAccount(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\EmailNotification $subject,        
        \Closure $proceed,        
        \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerInterface $customer,
        $type = self::NEW_ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REGISTERED,
        $backUrl = '',
        $storeId = null,
        $sendemailStoreId = null
    ) {
        echo'return'; exit;
        return ;     
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the Magento Core code, this class doesn't exist
`\Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerInterface`

You can use `\Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface` class instead, depends what you want to achieve.

The correct path for the class you are looking for should be:
`\Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface`

Also make sure your method name to be camelCase

`aroundNewAccount`

Your code should look like this:

```
namespace Vendor\Customer\Plugin;

class EmailNotificationPlugin
{
   public function aroundNewAccount(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\EmailNotification $subject,        
        \Closure $proceed,        
        \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface $customer,
        $type = self::NEW_ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REGISTERED,
        $backUrl = '',
        $storeId = null,
        $sendemailStoreId = null
    ) {
        echo'return'; exit;
        return ;     
    }
}
```

Comment: @devhs check this answer, might works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Customer\Plugin;

class EmailNotificationPlugin
{
   public function aroundNewAccount(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\EmailNotification $subject,        
        \Closure $proceed,        
        $customer,
        $type,
        $backUrl
        $storeId
        $sendemailStoreId
    ) {
        echo'return'; exit;
        return ;     
    }
}
```